# How to contain all LI inside ul width without wrapping up

Tags: css, html-lists, breadcrumbs, horizontallist

I want to create a breadcrumb structure which is like this:

nav1 > nav2 > nav3 etc.

So its a ul contained in div with having each nav1, nav2 and nav3 as li. Just like below:

```css
ul.nice-menu, ul.nice-menu ul {
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 /*position: relative;*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#zone-menu ul > li {
 /*width: 20%;*/
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul.nice-menu li {
 margin: 0;
 padding-left: 0;
 background-image: none;
}

ul.nice-menu-down li {
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ul.nice-menu li {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-top: 0;
 float: left;
 background-color: #eee;
 /*position: relative;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="zone-menu">
 <ul class="nice-menu">
  <li><a href="/">Another Test</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Another Test2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Menu Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">Test3 is a very long menu item. It should not be wrapped. Instead should truncate with ellipses</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I need to prevent the wrapping and show ellipses only in the last breadcrumb  item. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can not have that without specifying a width - at least not with this approach. You should rather go flexbox.

Comment: I can go with flexbox. Could you give a similar example

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem. I took the flexbox approach [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) suggested. I did put a maximum width on the  tag so you should adjust that to fit your needs when you implement your final solution. Here's the link to an example [pen](https://codepen.io/joseph-mueller/full/jwJNQJ) solving your problem.  Good luck!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #36c0e8;
}

a:hover {
  color: #2ea3c5;
}

ul.nice-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  display: flex;
}

ul.nice-menu li {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

ul.nice-menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 150px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding:20px 25px 20px 15px;
  position: relative;
}

ul.nice-menu li a::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top:40%;
  right: 2px;
  width: 10px; 
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: solid gray 2px;
  border-right: solid gray 2px;  
}

ul.nice-menu li:last-child a::after {
  content: none; 
}
```

```html
<ul class="nice-menu">
      <li><a href="/">Another Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Test</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Another Test2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Menu Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">Test3 is a very long menu item. It should not be wrapped. Instead should truncate with ellipses</a></li>
    </ul>
```